# @Autowired always getting null

Tags: spring

I have a Java interface:

```
public interface TestRequestDAO {
    ...
}
```

And the Implementation of the interface:

```
@Component
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/resources/my-context.xml")
public class TestRequestDAOImpl implements TestRequestDAO {
    ...
}
```

Now I am autowiring the Bean from another class like below and getting `null` always:

```
@Autowired
private TestRequestDAO requestDao;
```

Here is my spring context xml named as `my-context.xml` which is placed inside the `src/main/resources/` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd" >

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test.code"/>
</beans>
```

This example is made based one the other stackoverflow questions. I have added the annotation `@ContextConfiguration` since nothing worked with me.

I am using Maven and I have started from spring version `2.5.5` and ended with `4.0.1.RELEASE`. But nothing seemed to work with me. I have changed this version through maven:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <!--version>2.5.5</version-->
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A test would normally look something like this :

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations = "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public MyTest {...}
```

And then have Components injected into into it, as required. Don't make the test a component.

If the bean is not a test, don't call it TestXyz.